# Access to the MS Azure Data Catalog

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

I am trying to access the Azure Data Catalog home-page from within my organization:
https://usw-su1.azuredatacatalog.com/#/home

When I click on the above link, I instead land on the provision page:
https://usw-su1.azuredatacatalog.com/provision

I am not sure what exactly is causing this and I am new to Azure. Is it due to certain configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

The way you navigate to your company's catalog portal is by navigating to https://www.azuredatacatalog.com. This will then resolve to the portal for your company. In other words, everyone, from every company, goes to this same URL and based on your login identity it will connect you to the right catalog.